# Choose specific item from sharepoint list as default value?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, infopath, forms-services

In SharePoint I have a list full of people from AD with a Name (presence). I have another drop down menu with different items, so based on this drop down menu I want to be able to specify who should be emailed.

So once an item is chosen from the drop down menu, a person is chosen from the list to be set as a default value for another control so I can specify to send an email to that person.

How can I change the default value of a control to be a specific item in a list, not just the first item?

I would prefer to not use any hard coding options, if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an InfoPath form for entry instead.  InfoPath lets you set rules and such so that when you fill in one value, it populates another based on a formula or value.

Answer (score 0):

Go throw this link

http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2008/12/24/creating-a-sharepoint-list-parent--child-relationship---out.aspx

http://koobarspoint.blogspot.in/2010/06/cascading-drop-downs-with-infopath-2010.html